# While creating angular-element, multiple chunk files are generated. How to I merge all of them into one

Tags: angular, webpack, web-component, angular-elements, ngx-build-plus

I have created an angular element and bundled it using ngx-build-plus.
After bundling, other than the main,vendor, polyfills etc, I have 100+ chunk files in my dist folder.

How do I merge them all into one file.
How do I use these files in another JavaScript app?

[image: dist folder]

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `--single-bundle true`?
https://github.com/manfredsteyer/ngx-build-plus

Comment: this seems not to work with lazyloaded modules